# What is the right way to persist classifier model and incrementally train it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, pickle

I am writing a text classifier that looks at a bunch of strings and classifies them. I have a large number of these strings generated daily from an application. Let's say I am running my script for the first time today. I will fit the model to all the strings I have so far. At this point I want to save the model on the disk.

Tomorrow, I will load the model and use it to predict labels on new set of strings. I will then manually look at the predictions. The ones that were incorrectly made, I will correct the labels and feed them as new training set, to improve it. And so on!

Questions:

1. Is pickle dumping and loading the right/recommended way to persist models?
2. If I run 'fit' on a pre-trained model (loaded from pickle), will it do a new fitting from scratch? or will it add to its knowledge?

Here's what I am doing:

```
## learn.py
train_data  = ['list', 'of', 'input', 'strings']
labels      = ['list', 'of', 'output', 'labels']
tfidf_vec   = TfidfVectorizer()
clf         = MultinomialNB()

# build tf-idf matrix
train_tfidf = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(data)

# train classifier
clf.fit(train_tfidf, labels)

# persist vocabulary and model
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as outf:
    pickle.dump(tfidf_vec, outf) # need to save vocabulary and tfidf
    pickle.dump(clf, outf)       # need to save the classifier



## predict.py
test_data  = ['list', 'of', 'strings', 'to', 'classify']
labels     = ['list', 'of', 'output', 'labels']

# load tfidf_vec and clf from pickle
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as inf:
    tfidf_vec = pickle.load(inf)
    clf = pickle.load(inf)

# compute tfidf of new strings with learned vocabulary
test_tfidf = tfidf_vec.transform(test_data)

# predict labels
predicted = clf.predict(test_tfidf)
```

This works as expected. But I want to know if this is the right way to persist.
And also, next time when I run `learn.py`, how can I add to the knowledge, rather than making it learn from scratch? Even without persistence, if I run 'fit' back to back twice in the same script, does it fit from scratch?

Comment: " But I want to know if this is the right way to persist." - what do you mean by "right way"? Does it work for you? If it does, it is the "right way."

Comment: I'm guessing that this is the "right way" http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Each call to `fit()` learns the model from scratch again. If you want incremental learning, using `partial_fit()` is the right way in scikit-learn. But its only available for [some estimators which is documented here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning).

Comment: Anyways for very large data, the `TfidfVectorizer` is not recommended, [using HashingVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#extracting-features) is the "right way".

Comment: Thanks Cory and Vivek. Your links are very helpful and answer my question. Please convert your comments to answers so I can accept them?